# Overlap detection, nearest neighbors

Tags: collision-detection, quadtree, octree, search

I'm trying to get something similar to the Nearest Neightbor Problem, except I only want neighbors with radius overlapping a radius, and all of them.

I'll explain my problem before explaining what I think I need.
I have entities made out of voxels, where i want complete collision between all voxels. I'll do this by only doing collision checks for other entities within the maximum radius of the 'this' entity plus its velocity magnitude, *including* the radii of those other entities. That is a whole other problem in itself, but something that I can handle. What I need right now is a way of populating the list of collisions 'this' needs to check.

**Take a set of entities with arbitrary size/radius, make lines/circles/spheres out of their radii; given one of those spheres, get a list of all other spheres which overlap it.**
Cubes would also work instead of spheres if its somewhy substantially faster.

Ofcourse I could just iterate over all entities, but that would be n^2 time, and I would like to have thousands of entities. I could perhaps bruteforce it with a compute shader, but I'd like to avoid that.

Sofar I've been thinking have a k-tree store all entity positions, then have each entity make a sort of footprint on the nodes as one step, in the next step, check for nodes belonging to this which also have the footprint of another entity.
So how do I make a quadtree in a way which I can set and get footprints from in a way that isnt hideous? Or is there a completely different better way?

edit: [found this](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/ImprovedAlgoFixedRadiusNeighbProb.pdf) paper but its quite over my head

Comment: Doesn't this reduce to "how can I efficiently find all objects inside a given sphere?" (Not sure if I'm getting it right. A picture would help.)

Comment: I can easily do that, but a simple approach results in n^2 time

Comment: I get that; I only mean to ask if we could be simplify and generalise this question by phrasing it differently. I'm unfamiliar with the problem itself, just a writer passing by. :)